# Policy issue with transform function for AWS firehose records using Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am configuring record transformation for a firehose stream using Lambda. The problem is that the transform function is never invoked when a new record comes into firehose.

I debugged this further and found out the policy should allow `invokeFunction` at firehose role and should allow `getRecords` on the Kinesis stream at Lambda. But I do not have any Kinesis stream. Only the firehose stream which does not have `getRecords` action.

I read through their documentation:

- https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-firehose/faqs/,
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/controlling-access.html

but couldn't find an example for configuring Lambda policy to use as Firehose transform function.

While it is explained extensively about how to configure the firehose, the Lambda side doesn't have much information about IAM policies required.

Has anyone configured this successfully with proper policies?

---

**UPDATE:**

Firehose stream policy has access to S3 bucket (GetBucketLocation, ListBucket, ListBucketMultipartUploads, GetObject, PutObject)

Also the Lambda invocation permission as mentioned below.

```
{
  "Sid": "",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "lambda:InvokeFunction",
    "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration"
  ],
  "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:function:my_test_function:$LATEST"
}
```

At the Lambda side, in the console I selected Kinesis option for triggers. But it allows to select only the Kinesis streams from the `Kinesis stream` dropdown. What I am looking for is a Firehose stream where record transformation is allowed. But this Firehose stream does not appear in the dropdown at all.

Furthermore,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html explains the permissions required for Kinesis trigger (kinesis:GetRecords to read records from Kinesis stream)

But https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-kinesisfirehose.html does not provide any information about required permissions for Firehose at all. If I use same permissions as that of Kinesis stream, the Lambda does not trigger at all.

Comment: The Lambda function would only need enough permissions to perform the API calls that are actually made by the function. What errors are you seeing in CloudWatch Logs for the Lambda function?

Comment: Updated the questions with more details. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please expand upon what you are trying to accomplish? For example, is this correct... "You have an existing Kinesis Firehose stream that is receiving data via PUT and is saving to Amazon S3. You wish to add an AWS Lambda function that will transform the data as it flows through Kinesis. The function is passed a record from Firehose, modifies the data record and returns it back to Firehose. The information record is fully self-sufficient, and there is no need to read/write additional information to/from other services like Amazon S3". Is that correct?

Comment: What makes you think that you need to add permissions to the Lambda function? What AWS services is it calling (if any)? What errors are you seeing in CloudWatch Logs for the function?

Comment: You are right. While Kinesis stream requires `kinesis:GetRecords` permission at Lambda, Firehose does not require any trigger configuration at all. That solved my problem

Comment: The odd part is the Lambda logs in Cloudwatch shows invocations while the monitoring tab in Lambda does not show invocations from Firehose. That led me to believe the Lambda is not invoked.